# How to properly annotate generics (e.g list<T>, class<T>) in eclipse.microprofile.openApi

Tags: java, annotations, openapi, payara

Im currently working on Payara 5.2022.1 with OpenApi: 3.0.0 to generate YAML and everything was fine till I found out my annotations above `Class<T>` or `List<T>` doesnt work as intended? What I mean:

```
public class RestResponse extends BasicOperation {
    private RulesData rulesData;
    private ResultList<Device> resultDataList;
```

```
public class ResultList<T> extends BasicOperation {
    private List<T> dataList;
    public ResultList(Status status, Value value, boolean isExpanded) {
        super(status, value, isExpanded);
    }
}
```

```
public class Device {
    private String mac;
    private DeviceDescription description;
    private HomeType homeType;
}
```

and `/openapi` do something like this

```
RestResponse:
      exclusiveMaximum: false
      exclusiveMinimum: false
      minLength: 0
      uniqueItems: false
      maxProperties: 0
      minProperties: 0
      type: object
      properties:
        rulesData:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/RulesData'
        resultDataList:
          exclusiveMaximum: false
          exclusiveMinimum: false
          minLength: 0
          uniqueItems: false
          maxProperties: 0
          minProperties: 0
          nullable: false
          readOnly: false
          writeOnly: false
          deprecated: false
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ResultList'
        value:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Value'
        isExpanded:
          type: boolean
        code:
          type: string
        error:
          type: string
        status:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Status'
      nullable: false
      readOnly: false
      writeOnly: false
      deprecated: false
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BasicOperation'
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/BasicOperation'
```

```
ResultList:
      exclusiveMaximum: false
      exclusiveMinimum: false
      minLength: 0
      uniqueItems: false
      maxProperties: 0
      minProperties: 0
      type: object
      properties:
        dataList:
          items:
            type: object
        value:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Value'
        isExpanded:
          type: boolean
        code:
          type: string
        error:
          type: string
        status:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Status'
      nullable: false
      readOnly: false
      writeOnly: false
      deprecated: false
      allOf:
      - $ref: '#/components/schemas/StandardResponse'
```

and what Im expecting is information which class was used instead of `T` so I want to get something similar to this:

```
ResultList:
      exclusiveMaximum: false
      exclusiveMinimum: false
      minLength: 0
      uniqueItems: false
      maxProperties: 0
      minProperties: 0
      type: object
      properties:
        dataList:
          items:
            oneOf:{$ref: '#/components/schemas/Device}
        [...]
```

Or

```
RestResponse:
      exclusiveMaximum: false
      exclusiveMinimum: false
      minLength: 0
      uniqueItems: false
      maxProperties: 0
      minProperties: 0
      type: object
      properties:
        rulesData:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/RulesData'
        resultDataList:
          exclusiveMaximum: false
          exclusiveMinimum: false
          minLength: 0
          uniqueItems: false
          maxProperties: 0
          minProperties: 0
          nullable: false
          readOnly: false
          writeOnly: false
          deprecated: false
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ResultList<Device>'
       [...]
```

When it comes to annotations: `@Schema` works fine with `implementation` and `type` but when it comes to `oneOf`, `anyOf` it doesnt have any effect I belive I tried everything: `@Schema(oneOf = Device.class` OR `anyOf = {Device.class})` OR `ResultList.class` instead of `Device.class`. above these classes/variables and it still doesnt work? I mean there is no effect on `/openapi`